# Fried TPS61030PWP

Tags: boost, converter

I have constructed the circuit below which I put together based on the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61030.pdf). I am testing this circuit using a bench power supply. I have tried 1.8V and 2.7V supplies. With no load or a resistive load instead of outputting 5V w/very little current draw this circuit draws ~1A from the supply and fries itself. I have built this a couple times with different hardware so I am pretty certain it is a schematic problem. Is there an obvious problem I am missing? Before I finish I plan to split the PGND from the others except at one point. However I can't see how that would continue to ruin my chips.

[image]

Update: I built this on a pcb and it works properly now.

Comment: What does your layout look like?

Comment: What do you have connected to the FB pin?

Comment: @uint128_t I have a DIP breakout for the TPS61030. I am trying to test the circuit on a breadboard.

Comment: @DoxyLover The voltage divider on the right of the schematic. A 1.9M and a 200k Resister.

Comment: Breadboards and switching converters typically do not mix. You may want to try building the circuit on a perfboard, or better yet, a proper PCB. Also, (probably not the source of your issue, but) I don't think you need the divider, it looks like FB can be left unconnected for 5V.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the input, i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably due to your layout. Section 13.2 in the datasheet shows a good example and you should definitely follow this.

The most critical part is that the output cap and input cap grounds must be directly connected to each other very close in distance with very thick traces and only then should you tie it back to your main GND. Reason for this is there is a very high current spike that occurs when the internal FET switch opens and the inductor dumps its stored energy into the output cap (to boost the voltage). This results in a very fast current spike into VOUT and into the GND connection of the output cap and it needs to go somewhere. A very low impedance path between output cap and input cap GND causes this current spike be returned through the input cap and away from the rest of your circuit. (Red arrow in diagram below).

For best performance, you should even remove any thermal ties on the input caps and output caps to reduce the inductance and resistance.

Also you should be using the ceramic capacitors that they recommend for both input and output capacitors. Other types have high ESR (effective series resistance) and/or inductance resulting in higher voltage ripple and voltage spikes.

Also, it should be obvious that this part of the circuit should not be done on a solderless breadboard for reasons mentioned above :)

Also, please provide the part number of the inductor. You need to make sure you are not hitting saturation. The IC you chose does not seem to indicate any current protection for the internal switch and choosing too small an inductor (in current rating) will damage that switch from overcurrent due to inductor saturation. Hope that helps, -Vince
[image: Critical Ground Switching Current]

Comment: Thanks for the walk through Vince! Very informative. When I first posted this question I was testing on a breadboard. Once I tested it out on a pcb according to the manufacturer's specifications things worked much better.